# Flex 4 Scroller Adjust Speed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, scroll

I have a `<s:Scroller>` component that wraps around my entire application. My client has mentioned that the scroller scrolls too fast at certain times, and too slow at others.

Here are the four most common ways that you can scroll the `<s:Scroller>`, and here is my client's opinion of each:

1. Use the mouse wheel: speed is good
2. Drag the thumb: speed is up to the user (obviously)
3. Repeatedly tap the up/down arrows: speed is way to slow (sit and tap all day)
4. Press and hold the up/down arrows: speed is way to fast (hard to stop where you want)

As you can see, I have the mouse wheel under control. I'm not sure how I can adjust the speed mentioned in items 3 and 4. How can I do that?

As a side note, the speed mentioned in item 4 seems to slow down as the thumb gets smaller. If the thumb is really large it likes to wrap speed (please excuse the tired reference to Star Trek) to either the top or bottom.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are other lists different than the Flex list in these regards?  What technologies allow you to control item 3 and 4?  Don't HTML lists exhibit the same problem?  Or how about the web browser that displays this page?  Or your Flash Builder IDE?  Or MS Word?  Should you introduce your client to the page up / page down keys?

Comment: haha yah Flextras point stands, different input devices and different platforms supply different values, this shouldn't be too much of a shock.  in terms of getting around it you could add event listeners and adjust the scroll values yourself based on deltas or whatever info you get from flash player/AIR.  Also you'd want to stopImmediatePropagation() on the events to stop the control from handling the event itself too.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Good points. I would, if possible like to override these values, and replace them with ones which will offer a uniform experience.